# fail to send email using codeigniter : parameter 1 expect to be string, array given

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, email

```html
$this->db->select_sum('tariff');
  $this->db->where('request_id = ' .$request_id);
  $query = $this->db->get('excel'); 
  $message = $query->result();
  print_r($message);
  
  $this->db->select('email');
  $this->db->where('request_Id = ' .$request_id);
  $query = $this->db->get('request');
  $to = $query->result();
  print_r($to);
  
  $subject = "something..";
  $headers = 'From: maifirst1@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
     'Reply-To: maifirst1@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
     'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

  mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

i want to send email that the address is store in database, so i should get the value from this :

```
        $this->db->select('email');
        $this->db->where('request_Id = ' .$request_id);
        $query = $this->db->get('request');
        $to = $query->result();
```

any suggestion?

Comment: Is `print_r($to);` actually returning a valid email address?

Comment: it gives me : [email] => maymay_first@yahoo.com

Comment: it says, "Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: What result does `var_dump($to)` give you?

Comment: ["email"] => string(22) "maymay_first@yahoo.com"

Comment: This makes little sense o_O. What about `echo $to;`?

Comment: the email address doesn't appear

Comment: Try replacing `$to = $query->result();` with `$to = $query->row();` and add `var_dump($to)` straight after it.

Comment: mail() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Comment: Try `mail($to->email, $subject, $message, $headers);` again. Providing you still have `$to = $query->row();`

Comment: mail() expects parameter 3 to be string, array given. do i have to do the same way for $message?? because the $message is the result from SUM(tariff)

Comment: That's another error as the one stated. Probably the same issue as your $to parameter.

Comment: On the $message part, do the same `$to = $query->row();` and give us the results of `var_dump($message);`

Comment: mail() expects parameter 3 to be string, object given

Comment: i dont know how to express it in the mail() function, since the $message is the result from sum query, not from the value of one field

Comment: What is the result of $message when you dump it? Also consider to read more info about [Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: thank you for your answer, my script work perfectly

Answer (score 2):

Changing `$to` to `$to['email']` would fix the problem.

Comment: What is the error? Because $to is an array, and $to['email'] will give you a string, so technically it will solve the problem.

Comment: This is a type of comment.

Comment: A type of comment?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using $to variable inside your model. Just do this

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('email', array('request_Id' => $request_id));   
 return $query->result_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

On your mail() function should be $to->email since the return of the query is an object.

> mail($to->email, $subject, $message, $headers);